# Mobile View of Website

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm currently developing a site that can be found at http://bnlfinance.com, and I'm having issues with bootstrap with wordpress.  The homepage, and the posts, do not resize correctly on mobile.  The about us page does resize.  I'm sure it's something simple, but this is the first website that I've created using wordpress.  Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm whether you have this line of code in your head tags

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

make sure you also have

```
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Actually the 3 tags should come first in the head

Plus make sure you have the correct path to your javascript files. Note jquery.js file should be loaded before bootstrap js file...place reference to both files at the end of the body tag just before

```
    </body>
```

For example

```
       <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
       <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 2  tags showing on about page. check and remove if you have any hardcoded html on any php file remove it. 
just create one `header.php` then all header code in `header.php`.
create one named `footer.php` and and all footer code in `footer.php`.
and for `page.php` just call `get_header()` and `get_footer()` and standard Wordpress Loop and then `the_content()` function .. 
so basically `page.php` file will be like that :

```
    <?php         
    get_header();
    if ( have_posts() ) {
     while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        the_title();
        the_content();
      } 
    } 
    get_footer();
    ?>
```